# xampp, php and mysql require function error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I am working on a membership system but every time run my index page i get this error and i dont even understand it please help

> Warning: require(Tutorials\mysql.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Tutorials\index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Tutorials\mysql.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Tutorials\index.php on line 3

Comment: what's no clear? `No such file or directory`

Comment: use [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to tell the interpreter to start looking in \xampp\htdocs\xampp\Tutorials for this file.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12820243#12820243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open index.php and change line 3 from

```
require(Tutorials\mysql.php)
```

to

```
require(mysql.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file index.php on line 3 it requires you to have a file mysql.php but that file is missing or not found by the interpreter on the location given.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\xampp\php\` and find the file `php.ini`.

Find the setting `include_path` and add the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs`

In the end you should have something that looks like:

`include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs` or similar.

Don't forget to restart your XAMPP stack!

Afterwards, your stack will look for files that you're trying to include/require in the new path that you've set.

Also in your require line in index.php, try the following:

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Tutorials/mysql.php');`

This will make it very explicit the path of the file you're trying to include.